# How to use Node.js express async callback response with a Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, async.js

I'm new to node and trying to understand how to use async call inside an other async function, here's an example.

My routing:

```
/**
*  PAGE: PROFILE EXPOSITIONS
*/
exports.expositions = async(function* (req, res) {
        respond(res, 'users/profile/exhibitors', ProfileResponse.expositions( req ));
});
```

Here's what ProfileResponse.expositions look like

```
exports.expositions = function*(req) {
    return {
        title: "Expositions",
        user: req.user,
        path: "/profile",
        waiting_exposition_requests: yield UserService.getWaitingExpositionRequest(req.user.id)
    };
};
```

I'm trying to use getWaitingExpositionRequest which looks like this

```
exports.getWaitingExpositionRequest = function*(userId) {
    let currentUser = User.find(userId);
    let waiting_exposition_requests = [];
    currentUser.exposition_requests.forEach(function(exposition_request) {
        if(exposition_request.status === "waiting_for_exhibitor") {
            waiting_exposition_requests.push(exposition_request);
        }
    });
    return waiting_exposition_requests;
};
```

But in the console I get a Promise error, any idea how I can use this async function returned? I'm sure it's a syntax error but I'm a little lost with the async stuff.

Comment: `I get a Promise error,` can you be specific

Comment: I don't see where you're even using promises, just generators (`function*`).